# Нумерация строк в QTextEdit

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qtextedit, qplaintextedit

Как реализовать нумерацию строк в `QTextEdit`, 
что-то как на примере *Excel* или *Notepad++*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextEdit, QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout


class Text(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        text_edit = QTextEdit('Какой то текст')
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(text_edit)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Text()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Попробуйте создать собственный класс(унаследованный от `QTextEdit`), где Вы будете специально выделять область для вот этих номеров, а затем, с помощью слота `textChanged` , при добавлении - удалении новой строки Вы будете ставить номера. Либо же сразу расставьте номера в методе инициализации(для первого варианта), а затем по мере увеличения строк(больше, чем уже есть), увеличивайте и номера. Ссылка на [документацию](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#textChanged).(Qt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Реализуем редактор в классе `CodeEditor()`, который представляет собой виджет, наследующий `QPlainTextEdit()`.

В классе `LineNumberArea()` рисуем номера строк
и размещаем его над левой границей области просмотра `CodeEditor()`.

В классе `CodeEditor()` изменяем размер и рисуем номера строк в `LineNumberArea`. 
Нам нужно делать это, когда меняется количество строк в редакторе
и когда прокручивается область просмотра редактора (`viewport()`). 
Конечно, это также делается при изменении размера редактора. 
Мы делаем это в `updateLineNumberArea()`.

В конструкторе мы подключаем наши слоты к сигналам в `QPlainTextEdit`. 
Всякий раз, когда положение курсора меняется, мы выделяем текущую строку
в функции `highlightCurrentLine()`.

> void QPlainTextEdit::[**blockCountChanged**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#blockCountChanged)(int newBlockCount)
> Этот сигнал генерируется всякий раз, когда изменяется количество блоков. 
> Количество новых блоков передается в newBlockCount.

Подробности смотрите в описании [**Примера редактора кода**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-codeeditor-example.html).

Вот пример реализации на *PyQt*:

```
import sys
import numpy as np

from PyQt5 import Qt

class LineNumberArea(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, editor):
        super().__init__(editor)
        self.myeditor = editor

    def sizeHint(self):
        return Qt.Qsize(self.editor.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.myeditor.lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(event)


class CodeEditor(Qt.QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.lineNumberArea = LineNumberArea(self)

        self.blockCountChanged[int].connect(self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth)
        self.updateRequest[Qt.QRect,int].connect(self.updateLineNumberArea)
        self.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self.highlightCurrentLine)

        self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)
        
        self.setPlainText("""
        Класс QPlainTextEdit предоставляет виджет,
        который используется для редактирования и
        отображения обычного текста.
        """)


    def lineNumberAreaWidth(self):
        digits = 1
        count = max(1, self.blockCount())
        while count >= 10:
            count   /= 10
            digits  +=  1
        space = 3 + self.fontMetrics().width('9') * digits
        return space


    def updateLineNumberAreaWidth(self, _):
        self.setViewportMargins(self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0, 0, 0)


    def updateLineNumberArea(self, rect, dy):

        if dy:
            self.lineNumberArea.scroll(0, dy)
        else:
            self.lineNumberArea.update(0, rect.y(), self.lineNumberArea.width(),
                       rect.height())

        if rect.contains(self.viewport().rect()):
            self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)


    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)

        cr = self.contentsRect();
        self.lineNumberArea.setGeometry(Qt.QRect(cr.left(), cr.top(),
                    self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), cr.height()))


    def lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(self, event):
        mypainter = Qt.QPainter(self.lineNumberArea)

        mypainter.fillRect(event.rect(), Qt.Qt.lightGray)

        block       = self.firstVisibleBlock()
        blockNumber = block.blockNumber()
        top = self.blockBoundingGeometry(block).translated(self.contentOffset()).top()
        bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()

        height = self.fontMetrics().height()
        while block.isValid() and (top <= event.rect().bottom()):
            if block.isVisible() and (bottom >= event.rect().top()):
                number = str(blockNumber + 1)
                mypainter.setPen(Qt.Qt.black)
                mypainter.drawText(0, top, self.lineNumberArea.width(), height,
                 Qt.Qt.AlignRight, number)

            block  = block.next()
            top    = bottom
            bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()
            blockNumber += 1


    def highlightCurrentLine(self):
        extraSelections = []

        if not self.isReadOnly():
            selection = Qt.QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()

            lineColor = Qt.QColor(Qt.Qt.yellow).lighter(160)

            selection.format.setBackground(lineColor)
            selection.format.setProperty(Qt.QTextFormat.FullWidthSelection, True)
            selection.cursor = self.textCursor()
            selection.cursor.clearSelection()
            extraSelections.append(selection)
        self.setExtraSelections(extraSelections)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)

    txt = CodeEditor()
    txt.setStyleSheet("""QPlainTextEdit{
      font-family:'Consolas'; 
      color: #ccc; 
      font-size: 20px;
      background-color: #2b2b2b;}""")
    txt.setGeometry(400, 100, 600, 400)
    txt.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Qt.Qsize` -> `Qt.QSize`, `import numpy as np` не нужен, в `updateLineNumberAreaWidth` второй параметр `_` не нужен, соответственно `self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)` -> `self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth()`

Comment: @gil9red спасибо, кое-что подправил.